# Cannot save new object in a one to one relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I am using [this article](http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/) to make a one-to-one relationship between my two objects - `Site` and `WebOptions`.  Site is already present.  a record in WebOptions may or may not be present.  When it is, my mappings work fine.  When it is not, my system blows up trying to create a new record.

Here is my site class (the important bits)

```
public class Site : CoreObjectBase
{
    public virtual int SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual WebOptions WebOptions { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my web options class (important parts again)

```
public class WebOptions : CoreObjectBase
{
    public virtual int WebOptionsId { get; set; }

    private int SiteId { get; set; }
    private Site Site { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping for `Site` is

```
HasOne<WebOptions>(x => x.WebOptions)
    .Cascade.All();
```

And the mapping for `WebOptions` is

```
Id(Reveal.Property<WebOptions>("SiteId")).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Site");
HasOne<Site>(Reveal.Member<WebOptions, Site>("Site"))
    .Constrained()
    .ForeignKey();
```

In the data, the table behind Site has no foreighn key field to WebOptions, but the table behind WebOptions contains the SiteId.  In my code, I am already getting the site and use `site.WebOptions.SomeSetting` and would like to keep it that way.

My problem is this.  If I deviate from this mapping at all, my model breaks and no weboptions are returned while several records are saved into the weboptions table (duplicates).  But, when I try to save a new `WebOptions` object, I get

> Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1

I have a repository class with 2 save methods:

```
public sealed class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : CoreObjectBase
{
    public void SaveWithDependence<K>(T entity, K dependant) where K : CoreObjectBase
    {
        entity.Validate();
        dependant.Validate();

        using (ITransaction tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            Session.SaveOrUpdate(dependant);
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }

    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        entity.Validate();

        using (ITransaction tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

When no `WebOptions` is found, I am doing this when making a new one:

```
var options = site.WebOptions;

if (options == null)
{
    options = new WebOptions(site);
    site.WebOptions = options;
}
```

And the constructor looks like this to set the private variables

```
public WebOptions(Site site)
{
    Site = site;
    SiteId = site.SiteId;
}
```

And then to save, I have tried to following:

```
siteRepository.Save(site);
```

and

```
siteRepository.SaveWithDependence(site, options);
```

and

```
optionsRepository.Save(options);
```

and

```
optionsRepository.SaveWithDependence<Site>(options, site);
```

All of them return the above error.  My session declaration looks like this

```
sessionFactory =  
            Fluently.Configure().Database(
                FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.DefaultSchema("dbo")
                    .ConnectionString(c => c
                        .FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyDatabase"))
                        .AdoNetBatchSize(20))
                    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionManager>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "managed_web"))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I really need to be able to save a new `WebOptions` record if one doesn't exist, but I can't seem to get it to work with my one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I spent all that time putting that together and then in playing around with it, I removed one line of code - just to see what would happen.

In the constructor for `WebOptions` I removed this single line:

```
SiteId = site.SiteId;
```

for a constructor that looks like this:

```
public WebOptions(Site site)
{
    Site = site;
}
```

Then, I save only my `WebOptions` object like this:

```
optionsRepository.Save(options);
```

My best guess is that since I am using an ID field for the 'SiteId' property in fluent, fluent doesn't allow me to manually set that value.  Setting the private property `Site` in addition to setting the `Site.WebOptions` property, must set up the one-to-one relationship for fluent/nhibernate to deduce what value to place into the SiteId field.

Further inspection of the article posted above shows that this is the way it has to be done.  I just happened to miss this very important piece of information:

> The **public constructor**, taking a `Client` parameter, is the one you will use in your code whenever you want to assign a client some alimentary habits, such as: `AlimentaryHabits = new AlimentaryHabits(this);`. The protected constructor is used internally by NHibernate, and must be present. You can completely ignore it.

I am going to leave this post and answer in the event someone else has this issue and I can save them a little bit of time and frustration.